# PHP: Re-sorting Display Order with Selected Rows and Inputted Starting Point Value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting, data-structures

Just attended a concluding interview where the interviewer assigned me a task involving CRUD operations. The task specifically entails displaying data sorted by the "display_order" column. Within the table list, there is a checkbox that allows users to rearrange the order. To do so, one must check the box and specify a starting point for the display order. For instance:

Example:
Starting point: 2
Original List:

| id | display order | checkbox |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 69 | 1 |  |
| 71 | 2 |  |
| 37 | 3 |  |
| 52 | 4 |  |
| 59 | 5 |  |
| 60 | 6 |  |
| 86 | 7 | checked |
| 84 | 8 |  |
| 77 | 9 | checked |
| 44 | 10 | checked |

Expected Result:

| id | display order | checkbox |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 69 | 1 |  |
| 86 | 2 |  |
| 77 | 3 |  |
| 44 | 4 |  |
| 71 | 5 |  |
| 37 | 6 |  |
| 52 | 7 |  |
| 59 | 8 |  |
| 60 | 9 |  |
| 84 | 10 |  |

The Result:

```
[
  {
    "id": "69",
    "sort": 1
  },
  {
    "id": "86",
    "sort": "2"
  },
  {
    "id": "77",
    "sort": "3"
  },
  {
    "id": "44",
    "sort": "4"
  },
  {
    "id": "52",
    "sort": 5
  },
  {
    "id": "71",
    "sort": 5
  },
  {
    "id": "37",
    "sort": 5
  },
  {
    "id": "59",
    "sort": "5"
  },
  {
    "id": "60",
    "sort": "6"
  },
  {
    "id": "84",
    "sort": "8"
  }
]
```

Another Example:
Starting point: 8

Expected Result:

| id | display order | checkbox |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 69 | 1 |  |
| 71 | 2 |  |
| 37 | 3 |  |
| 52 | 4 |  |
| 59 | 5 |  |
| 60 | 6 |  |
| 84 | 7 |  |
| 86 | 8 |  |
| 77 | 9 |  |
| 44 | 10 |  |

The Result:

```
[
  {
    "id": "69",
    "sort": 1
  },
  {
    "id": "71",
    "sort": 2
  },
  {
    "id": "37",
    "sort": 3
  },
  {
    "id": "52",
    "sort": 4
  },
  {
    "id": "59",
    "sort": 5
  },
  {
    "id": "60",
    "sort": 6
  },
  {
    "id": "86",
    "sort": "8"
  },
  {
    "id": "77",
    "sort": "9"
  },
  {
    "id": "44",
    "sort": "10"
  },
  {
    "id": "84",
    "sort": 11
  }
]
```

Here's what I have so far for the code:

```
public function reorder_list($request, $model = 'talk_news') {
    $inputted_display_order = 7;

    if (isset($request['sortable']) && $request['sortable']) {
        $this->setOrm(ORM::for_table($model));
        $sorted_ids = array_column($request['sortable'], 'id');
        $sorted_display_order = array_column($request['sortable'], 'sort');
        $first_display_order = reset($sorted_display_order);
        $last_display_order = end($sorted_display_order);
        $new_order = [];

        $query = $this->_orm->select('id')
            ->select('display_order')
            ->where_not_in('id', $sorted_ids)
            ->order_by_asc('display_order')
            ->find_array();

        $starting_display_order = $first_display_order == 1 ? count($sorted_display_order) + 1 : 1;

        foreach($query as $item) {
            $id = $item['id'];
            $display_order = $item['display_order'];

            $sort_value = $starting_display_order++;

            if ($display_order > $last_display_order && $first_display_order != 1) {
                $sort_value = $display_order;
            }

            if($display_order >= min($sorted_display_order) && $display_order <= max($sorted_display_order) && $first_display_order != 1) {
                $count_to_max = (max($sorted_display_order) + 1) - $display_order;
                $sort_value = $display_order + $count_to_max;
            }

            $new_order[] = [
                'id'   => $id,
                'sort' => $sort_value
            ];
        }

        $new_order = array_merge($new_order, $request['sortable']);

        usort($new_order, function ($a, $b) {
            return $a['sort'] - $b['sort'];
        });

        return $new_order;
    }
}
```

To replicate this, I'll provide the data from the query and for the $request['sortable']:

Sample Data for $query:

```
[{"id":"69","display_order":"1"},{"id":"71","display_order":"2"},{"id":"37","display_order":"3"},{"id":"52","display_order":"4"},{"id":"59","display_order":"5"},{"id":"60","display_order":"6"},{"id":"84","display_order":"8"},{"id":"74","display_order":"11"},{"id":"64","display_order":"12"},{"id":"25","display_order":"13"},{"id":"70","display_order":"14"},{"id":"73","display_order":"15"},{"id":"68","display_order":"16"},{"id":"38","display_order":"17"},{"id":"26","display_order":"18"},{"id":"5","display_order":"19"},{"id":"33","display_order":"20"},{"id":"41","display_order":"21"},{"id":"40","display_order":"22"},{"id":"55","display_order":"23"},{"id":"57","display_order":"24"},{"id":"61","display_order":"25"},{"id":"65","display_order":"26"},{"id":"66","display_order":"27"},{"id":"67","display_order":"28"},{"id":"46","display_order":"29"},{"id":"76","display_order":"30"},{"id":"78","display_order":"31"},{"id":"79","display_order":"32"},{"id":"81","display_order":"33"}]
```

Sample data for $request['sortable']

```
[{"id":"86","sort":"2"},{"id":"77","sort":"3"},{"id":"44","sort":"4"}]
```

Comment: "disrupts" in what way? Please give a clearer indication of the problem - what result did you get, and what result did you expect, for those two cases? Also it would really help if you provided some sample input data within your code block (e.g. in the form of a var_export output or JSON or something) so we can actually run and test it. Otherwise it's all a bit abstract (and fiddly).

Comment: @ADyson Sorry 'bout that, I have added 2 actual results from the example. And also provided sample data for $query and $request['sortable']. Thank You

Comment: I think you should first, sort the sortable items, those that are checked based on their sort value, and then, reorder all items in the list, placing checked items starting from the specified starting point, and adjusting the position of unchecked items accordingly. Try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could re-index `$request['sortable']` so that you have an array of `id`s indexed by `sort`. Then, for each display order take the id from the re-indexed array if it exists, else [`array_shift()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) next item from beginning of `$query`.

Something like:

```php
public function reorder_list($request, $model = 'talk_news') {

    if (isset($request['sortable']) && $request['sortable']) {
        $this->setOrm(ORM::for_table($model));
        $sorted_ids = array_column($request['sortable'], 'id');

        /* create array of ids indexed by sort */
        $sorted_display_order = array_column($request['sortable'], 'id', 'sort');

        $new_order = [];

        $query = $this->_orm->select('id')
            ->select('display_order')
            ->where_not_in('id', $sorted_ids)
            ->order_by_asc('display_order')
            ->find_array();

        $total_count = count($query) + count($sorted_ids);

        for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_count; $i++) {
            if (array_key_exists($i, $sorted_display_order)) {
                $id = $sorted_display_order[$i];
            } else {
                $id = array_shift($query)['id'];
            }
            $new_order[] = ['id' => $id, 'sort' => $i];
        }

        return $new_order;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have tested this and it worked well. Have not thought of re-indexing. Thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad I was able to help.